# syntax error in array pattern matching program?

Tags: haxe, flashdevelop

I typed [an array pattern matching example from the Haxe docs](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-pattern-matching-array.html) into [HaxeDevelop](http://haxedevelop.org/)

```
package;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Terrence Brannon
 */
class ArrayMatching 
{

    static public function main() : Void
    {
        var myArray = [1, 6];
        var match = switch(myArray) {
            case [2, _]: "0";
            case [_, 6]: "1";
            case []: "2";
            case [_, _, _]: "3";
            case _: "4";
        }

    trace(match); // 1
    }
}
```

and it refuses a GUI call to Refactor -> Code Formatting with the error "Syntax errors encountered. Could not format code."

However executing

```
haxe.exe -main ArrayMatching  --interp
```

yields

```
ArrayMatching.hx:21: 1
```

Comment: Did not encounter this problem in HaxeDevelop 5.2, if you are using 5.1 or earlier, you should try to update

Comment: This is HaxeDevelop 5.2.05 for .NET 3.5

Comment: Well, may be thats some other part of your project that is causing the problem, anyway if you can figure out concrete steps to reproduce the problem you should submit a bug report to HaxeDevelop repo https://github.com/fdorg/flashdevelop/